# Retornar os elementos de Fibonnaci do termo passado até o primeiro

Tags: ruby, recursão, fibonnaci

Fiz o retorno de alguns elementos específicos já, mas estou tentando retornar até o primeiro. No código abaixo fiz retornar determinado elemento, como crio agora de até o primeiro, até o quinto e até o decimo?

```
def element( f )
        return  f  if f <= 1
        element( f - 1 ) + element( f - 2 )
    end
```

Comment: Explique melhor a necessidade. Seja mais claro no que o algoritmo deve fazer. Deu para entender o que fez e que deseja vários números, mas como quer que isto seja fornecido? Sem saber onde quer chegar nenhum caminho serve.

Comment: Preciso que me retorne os elementos de fibonacci até o décimo, vou colocar um exemplo do erro e você tera uma ideia ! Obs: já tenho uma spec criada.

Fibonacci retorna os elementos de fibonnacci até o décimo
     Failure/Error: expect(Fibonacci.new.elements(10)).to eq [0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34, 55]

       expected: [0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34, 55]
            got: 10

       (compared using ==)
     # ./spec/fibonacci_spec.rb:29:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'

Finished in 0.04687 seconds (files took 1.27 seconds to load)
7 examples, 3 failures

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pela descrição quer devolver uma lista e não o termo final, então deve manipular os retornos com listas, algo assim:

```
def fibonacci(termo)
    return [] if termo == 0
    return [0] if termo == 1
    return [0, 1] if termo == 2 
    lista = fibonacci(termo - 1) 
    lista << lista[-2] + lista[-1]
    return lista
end
print fibonacci(10)
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/xMD4Kw). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/mrzunytq-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Python/FibonacciRecursiveSequence.py).

Comment: Vou tentar aqui ! Obrigado

Comment: @LucasCordeiro Veja no [tour/ a melhor forma de dizer obrigado.

Comment: Tudo bem ! 
Seu metodo deu quase certo, ele só me retorna dizendo expected: [0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34, 55]
            got: [0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34]
Tentei colocar outro return, mas ele me altera o got, como 0, 2, 2 enfim

Comment: Fiz uma pequena alteração, retirando o return list, e no return [0, 1] acrescentei mais um 1, ficando return [0 ,1 ,1], assim deu certo retornando até o quinto elemento e até o decimo elemento, menos para o primeiro

Answer (score 0):

Fiz como o Maniero falou, só fiz umas pequenas alterações !

Código:

```
def elements(n)
        return [0] if n == 0
        return [0] if n == 1
        return [0, 1, 1] if n == 2
        lista = elements(n - 1) 
        lista << lista[-2] + lista[-1]
    end
```